# Изменение значения value

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form method="post" action="http://1111.ru/hunt_conf.php" name="r2" target="h1">
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="farm"> 
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="check"> 
<input type="hidden" name="num" value="41">
</form>

<button id="startres" onclick="r2.submit(); res2=setInterval('r2.submit()', 63000); document.getElementById('stopres').style.display=' inline-block'; this.style.display='none';" title="skrigalii ON">Копать</button>

<button id="stopres" onclick="clearInterval(res2); document.getElementById('startres').style.display= 'inline-block'; this.style.display='none';" title="skrigalii OFF">Не копать (стоп)</button>
```

Можно ли сделать чтобы значение value="41" менялось?)

Comment: `<form onsubmit="return false;" ...`

Comment: Заголовок вопроса, должен содержать краткую  суть проблемы, а не крик души...

Answer (score 2):

> Можно ли сделать чтобы значение value="41" менялось?)

Да, можно:

```js
let frm = document.forms.r2;

  // изменить значение: 
frm.num.value = '42'; 

  // изменить тип (сделав видимым): 
frm.num.type = 'text';
```

```html
<form method="post" action="http://1111.ru/hunt_conf.php" name="r2" target="h1">
  <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="farm"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="check"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="num" value="41">
</form>
```